# JavaFx8 (+Maven): error when loading the fxml file

Tags: eclipse, maven, javafx-8, fxmlloader

I am trying to write a JavaFx8 application using Maven. I wrote a simple application main class and a fxml file (a root fxml file that does nothing).

When I try to load the fxml root file I have the error "Location is not set":

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/99550389.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2428)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2403)
    at org.aklal.todofx.tasks.App.initRootLayout(App.java:58)
    at org.aklal.todofx.tasks.App.start(App.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$56/1712616138.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/1268447657.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$52/511893999.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/1851691492.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$45(GtkApplication.java:126)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$42/584634336.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application org.aklal.todofx.tasks.App
```

I am not new to JavaFx8 and I already had this kind of error but this time I do not find the problem.

[image]

My classes are:
App.java

```
package org.aklal.todofx.tasks;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class App extends Application {

        private Stage primaryStage;
        private BorderPane rootLayout;

        public App() {
                System.out.println("TEST");
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
                this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
                this.primaryStage.setTitle("TEST App (JavaFx with Maven)");

                initRootLayout();
        }

        public void initRootLayout() {
                try {
                        //to check classpaths 
                        Unused un = new Unused();
                        System.out.println("TESTAPP\n\t" + this.getClass());

                        // Load root layout from fxml file.
                        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                        loader.setLocation(App.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
                        //loader.setLocation(App.class.getResource("TestRootLayout.fxml"));
                        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

                        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
                        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
                        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                        primaryStage.show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }


        public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
                return primaryStage;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                launch(args);
        }
}
```

RootLayout.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="1024.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
        <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
</BorderPane>
```

I checked the classpathes printing out the getClass output (Is that the correct way to have classpath?), to do so I wrote an "Unused.java" class in the fxml file package:

```
package org.aklal.todofx.tasks.view;

public class Unused {
        public Unused(){
                System.out.println("Unused\n\t" + this.getClass());
        }

}
```

When I run the App, the getClass ouputs are:

> Unused
>
> > ```
> >    class org.aklal.todofx.tasks.view
> > ```
>
> Unused APP
>
> > ```
> >    class org.aklal.todofx.tasks.App
> > ```

So in my opinion the path ("view/RootLayout.fxml") I give to loader.setLocation is correct, isn't it?.

I also tried to put the root fxml file (renamed TestRootLayout) in the main class' package, I still have the error.

Can anybody see an error?

### Note

I already wrote JavaFx apps but I never used Maven to do it, the purpose of this project is to set a JavaFx8 project with Maven. I think my problem does not come from Maven but I give you the commands I done to set my project, maybe there is something wrong:
I did the command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.aklal -DartifactId=javafx-with-maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I modified the pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.aklal</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-with-maven</artifactId>
  
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <name>javafx-with-maven</name>
  
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>JavaFXSimpleApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>        
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.aklal.todofx.tasks.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>    
    </build>
</project>
```

and then:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

and in Eclipse: Import -> Existing Projects into workspace

fxrt.jar is included in JRE System Library

### Update:

To check if the problem has not a more general reason, I wrote the main class with hard coded elements:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button bouton = new Button("Click");
        bouton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Clicked!"));
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(bouton);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFx8 with Maven");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

It works, so I guess everything is in order. The question remains: why does the setLocation not work?

### Update:

There is definitely a problem with the path to the fxml file. If I change:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(App.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
```

with:

```
String pathToFxml = "absolute_path/RootLayout.fxml";
URL fxmlUrl = new File(pathToFxml).toURI().toURL();
loader.setLocation(fxmlUrl);
```

then it works

Comment: Have you tried to change "view/RootLayout.fxml" to "RootLayout.fxml"?

Comment: If you check your JAR-file, where is your FXML-file located?

Comment: @Inge: yes I already tried

Comment: @Puce: good question, I am pretty new to Maven, for now the jar I created did not have fxml files. I guess I made a mistake, I will give one more try and let you know

Comment: add a " / " loader.setLocation(App.class.getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml"));

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> for now the jar I created did not have fxml files. I guess I made a
>   mistake, I will give one more try and let you know

You need to add the FXML file in a sub-directory of `src/main/resources` not `src/main/java`

If you call `App.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml")` then the FXML file has to be in the directory: `src/main/resources/mypackage/view` where mypackage is the package of the class App.

If you call it with a leading slash: `App.class.getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml")` then the FXML file has to be in the directory: `src/main/resources/view`

Double-check if the FXML-file is at the expected location in the JAR-file.

Comment: I made what you suggested and it works, thanks!!!! But I am confused about how things are working...  I guess I have to spend more time on Maven. In any case thank you a lot!!!

Comment: @OLeeCsobert The Java files get compiled by the compile goal of the Maven Compiler Plugin which looks at Java-files in src/main/java.
The resources goal of the Maven Resources Plugin processes files at src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

As Puce said, if you call `App.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml")` then the FXML file has to be in the directory: `src/main/resources/mypackage/view` where mypackage is the package of the class App.

So , instead of using App.class

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); 
loader.setLocation(App.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
```

Try ClassLoader

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); 
loader.setLocation(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
```